# How can we explain STARK with less math?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, starks

I am trying to understand STARK with not much math. I understand SNARK like this:
Computation → Arithmetic Circuit → R1CS → QAP → zk-SNARK

From the helpful article: https://z.cash/technology/zksnarks/

We have a computation with many steps that can prove something. We take that and create an arithmetic circuit (in simple words a algebraic equation). Then we have R1CS which is going to validate each of the steps were done correctly. Then we combine all these checks in to one with QAP (Quadratic Arithmetic Program - can be compared to converting an algebraic equation to a line or graph in 2D Space). This gives you a SNARK.

How can we similarly describe STARK?

Comment: R1CS & QAP isn't mandatory in SNARKs. PLONK has neither. That's there in older SNARKs like Pinocchio & Groth16